How to fix lifetime issue in Rust?
In summary, I want to have a function that digests a CSV file and depending on the existing values, it should decide with on_conflict if the current value or the new value should be used.
However, I get the following error when I try to implement the function:
error[E0597]: `original_contents` does not live long enough
  --> src/utils/result_writer.rs:66:17
   |
58 | fn get_updated_contents<'old, 'new, 'out>(
   |                         ---- lifetime `'old` defined here
59 |     original_contents: String,
   |     ----------------- binding `original_contents` declared here
...
66 |     let lines = original_contents.lines().skip(1);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
74 |                 temp_lines.push(on_conflict(&columns[descriptor_values.len()..columns.len()].to_vec(), &value_values).to_vec());
   |                                 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- argument requires that `original_contents` is borrowed for `'old`
...
88 | }
   | - `original_contents` dropped here while still borrowed

fn get_updated_contents<'old, 'new, 'out>(
    original_contents: String,
    descriptor_values: Vec<&str>,
    value_values: Vec<&str>,
    on_conflict: fn(&'old Vec<&'old str>, &'new Vec<&'new str>) -> &'out Vec<&'out str>,
) -> Vec<String>
    where 'old: 'out, 'new: 'out {

    let lines = original_contents.lines().skip(1);

    let temp_lines: Vec<Vec<&str>> = {
        let mut temp_lines = Vec::new();

        for line in lines {
            let columns: Vec<&str> = line.split(",").collect();
            if columns.starts_with(&descriptor_values) {
                temp_lines.push(on_conflict(&columns[descriptor_values.len()..columns.len()].to_vec(), &value_values).to_vec());
            } else {
                temp_lines.push(columns);
            }
        }

        temp_lines.sort_by(compare_lines);
        temp_lines
    };

    temp_lines
        .iter()
        .map(|line| line.join(","))
        .collect()
}


&'a Foo<'a> is very often wrong. What you usually want is &'a Foo<'b>: playground.

Thank you @Jmb, I tried your example but I couldn't implement the on_conflict function. I believe the function signature is not quite correct playground

If your function returns one of its arguments, then the lifetimes of the returned value must match those of the argument: playground (if the function may return either of its arguments, then the lifetimes of the returned value must match those of all the arguments: playground).

I fixed it by using Higher-Rank Trait Bounds.
fn get_updated_contents(
    old_contents: &str,
    descriptor_values: &[&str],
    value_values: &[&str],
    on_conflict: for<'a> fn(&'a [&'a str], &'a [&'a str]) -> &'a [&'a str],
) -> Vec<String> {
    let old_lines: Vec<Vec<&str>> = old_contents
        .lines()
        .skip(1)
        .map(|line| line.split(",").collect())
        .collect();

    let new_lines: Vec<Vec<&str>> = {
        let mut temp_lines: Vec<Vec<&str>> = Vec::new();
        let mut found = false;

        for i in 0..old_lines.len() {
            let columns = &old_lines[i];
            if columns.starts_with(&descriptor_values) {
                found = true;
                let mut new_line: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
                for i in 0..descriptor_values.len() {
                    new_line.push(descriptor_values[i]);
                }

                let old_values: &[&str] = &columns[descriptor_values.len()..columns.len()];
                let result = on_conflict(old_values, value_values);
                for value in result {
                    new_line.push(&value);
                }
                temp_lines.push(new_line);
            } else {
                temp_lines.push(columns.clone());
            }
        }

        if !found {
            let mut new_line = Vec::new();
            new_line.extend_from_slice(&descriptor_values);
            new_line.extend_from_slice(&value_values);
            temp_lines.push(new_line);
        }

        temp_lines.sort_by(compare_lines);
        temp_lines
    };

    new_lines
        .iter()
        .map(|line| line.join(","))
        .collect()
}

